# How to fetch content from other webpage and store in database

Tags: php, curl

Hell Friends

I need to fetch the race result from here

```
"http://www.drf.com/race-results/BHP/USA/2012-06-23/D"
```

and want to store in my database 
I need to fetch all record for race 1,race 2,race3 etc

Please suggest me 
I am using this code but its showing me full page I want only specific info

```
      <?php
       $ch = curl_init();   
      //Fetch the timeline
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.drf.com/race-results/BHP/USA/2012-06-24/D');
 //send data via $_GET
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, 0);

//do not return the header information
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);

//If SSL verification is needed. Delete if not needed
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);

    //Give me the data back as a string... Don't echo it.
      //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        //Warp 9, Engage!

       $content = curl_exec($ch);

       //Close CURL connection & free the used memory.

       curl_close($ch);
         ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte) library. It will let you scrape and parse remote sites with a well documented API. You can even follow links and submit forms.

Example usage from the documentation:

```
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();
```

Make requests with the request() method:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.symfony-project.org/');
```

The method returns a Crawler object (Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler).

Click on links:

```
$link = $crawler->selectLink('Plugins')->link();
$crawler = $client->click($link);
```

extract data based on CSS class and output the text:

```
$nodes = $crawler->filter('.error_list');
if ($nodes->count())
{
  die(sprintf("Authentification error: %s\n", $nodes->text()));
}

printf("Nb tasks: %d\n", $crawler->filter('#nb_tasks')->text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into PHP dom parser. [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Parse the HTML page to get the required data and save it into the database.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Curl would return the page's HTML code of the site, that is expected.

Go to the actual site, identify say, the div, in which the results are displayed. Then extract the data of the particular section using PHP dom parser or maybe even a string extract (easy but inefficient and not recommended).

Strip HTML tags from the section and save the required data,

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP simplehtmldom parser to extract contents from HTML http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/